# What Mapping dot update is?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

Trying to get the meaning of **Uniswap v3-core**, I rammed into an unexpected Solidity syntax which I cannot comprehend, so I need someone who could explain it.

the thing is about `UniswapV3Pool.sol` contract which can be found at both
[etherscan.io](https://etherscan.io/address/0x6Ab3bba2F41e7eAA262fa5A1A9b3932fA161526F#code) and [github](https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-core/blob/main/contracts/UniswapV3Pool.sol) of the project.

More to the point, there are the following lines:

```
406             flippedLower = ticks.update( 
407                 tickLower, 
408                 tick, 
409                 liquidityDelta, 
410                 _feeGrowthGlobal0X128, 
411                 _feeGrowthGlobal1X128, 
412                 secondsPerLiquidityCumulativeX128, 
413                 tickCumulative, 
414                 time, 
415                 false, 
416                 maxLiquidityPerTick 
417             );
```

but the `ticks` variable is just a `mapping`:

```
 93     mapping(int24 => Tick.Info) public override ticks;
```

1. So I do not get it. What `update` is called there?
2. There are some similar puzzling things, such as

```
386         position = positions.get(owner, tickLower, tickUpper);
```

where

```
 97     mapping(bytes32 => Position.Info) public override positions;
```

There is no `get` on a `mapping` as well. What is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UniswapV3Pool.sol` extends a specific `mapping` type by functions defined in the `Tick` library:

```
using Tick for mapping(int24 => Tick.Info);
```

The `Tick` library then defines the `update()` function ([GitHub source](https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-core/blob/main/contracts/libraries/Tick.sol#L110)).

---

Same goes with the `positions` mapping extended by the `Position` library ([GitHub source](https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-core/blob/main/contracts/libraries/Position.sol)), as well as few others.

```
using Position for mapping(bytes32 => Position.Info);
```

Here's the Solidity docs for `using ... for`: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/contracts.html#using-for

Comment: I've clean forgotten about it ....